# Delete files and folders with specific name from a certain directory

Tags: command-line

I have a folder `/home/userA/folderA` this folder contains many files and folders and subfolders. What I want to do is to delete all files that have certain names `data.txt` and `glass.txt`. I also want to delete any folder named `match` with all its contents. I'd be thankful for any advice in how to do this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can delete the files and folders in the subdirectories of `folderA`.

To remove the files, run:

```
find /home/userA/folderA/* -type f \( -name "data.txt" -or -name "glass.txt" \) -delete
```

and to remove the folders `match`:

```
find /home/userA/folderA/* -depth -name "match" -type d -exec rm -rf "{}" \;
```

Comment: its giving this error `find: invalid expression; I was expecting to find a ')' somewhere but did not see one.`

Comment: Try: `find /home/userA/folderA/* -depth -name "data.txt" -type f -exec rm {} \;` and `find /home/userA/folderA/* -depth -name "glass.txt" -type f -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: that did it :) thanks! will you update your answer to mark it as answered?

Answer (score 4):

And the verbose (python) option:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import shutil

# --------------------------------------------------------
reorg_dir = "/path/to/your/folder"
remove_files = ("data.txt", "glass.txt")
remove_dirs = ("match")
# ---------------------------------------------------------

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(reorg_dir):
    for name in files:
        if name in remove_files:
            os.remove(root+"/"+name)
    for dr in dirs:
        if dr in remove_dirs:
            shutil.rmtree(root+"/"+dr)
```

Copy the script into an empty file, set the directory and if you want/need: edit the list of files and folders to remove, save it as reorg.py and run it by the command:

```
python3 /path/to/reorg.py
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply run the following command (be careful and double check everything because this is not reversible!) This will delete any files that have the word data or glass in it that are .txt files.

`sudo rm -rf /home/userA/folderA/*data*.txt`

`sudo rm -rf /home/userA/folderA/*glass*.txt`

You can find any folder named match by using the locate commmand:

`locate match`

Once you find the paths, simply do the command above for the entire folder

`sudo rm -rf /path/to/match`

Best, 
Lev

Comment: Mind you: locate is not real-time. It uses a database and if a matching file is not yet in it it will not show with that command.

Comment: thanks for your answer! regarding the `match` folder answer, the problem is that i'm expecting more than 100 folder named `match` in this folder :)  this is why I'm asking for an easy solution :)

Comment: Take a look at the solution below from Nathan for the match problem, it will work great!

Comment: You should only use `sudo` when you really mean it, and there's no need for it here.